# Thors in battle versus Colossi

Tags: starcraft-2

As Terran facing a Protoss.
The Protoss goes for a standard army, Gateway units with Templars and Colossi.

The Terran has a standard bio ball with a few Ghosts and some Thors.

**Does the Thor High Impact Payload work against Colossi?**

*IF YES:*
**Is the Thors High Impact Payload worth using versus the Colossi or is it better to have the Thor focus the Gateway units?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The High Impact Payload does work against Colossi!**

But it is not worth using since the ground weapons is a lot more effective against a Colussus

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what this picture is showing, the Thor looks like he is using his ground attack.

Comment: @Resorath It is using its High Impact Payload. When the Thor attacks ground units, it shoots from its arms.

Comment: He is right (I'll delete my answer).  I only tested the Javelin Missile which doesn't attack the colossus, but when switching to the high-impact payload the thor will indeed attack the colossus